# Is there a way to get high/low values of selected bars?

Tags: plot, pine-script

With Pine Script, I would like to visualize pivot points (highs and lows) on a microlevel, concerning 3 bars according with the following condition for pivot highs:

```
(high[1] > high[0]) and (high[1] > high[2])
```

Next, I would like to visualize higher order pivot highs following the condition:

```
(pivothigh[1] > pivothigh[0]) and (pivothigh[1] > pivothigh[2])
```

Finally, I would like to make the same process for one further level.
The first step has been done, however, I have problems with my second aims. How can I get the pivot high of the microlevel pivot highs?

```
study("Pivot points")

//Define the width to look for pivot highs
leftBars = input(1)
rightBars= input(1)

pivhigh = pivothigh(high,leftBars,rightBars)

//plotting the pivot highs on the micro level (however, with an additional offset)
plotshape(pivhigh, style = shape.xcross, location = location.abovebar, color=color.green, offset = -rightBars)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use arrays to store and evaluate the pivots and add the pivot high/low values to the higher order arrays as they occur.

```
var float[] first_order_pvhs = array.new_float()
var float[] second_order_pvhs = array.new_float()
var float[] third_order_pvhs = array.new_float()

if high[1] > high[0] and high[1] > high[2]
    array.unshift(first_order_pvhs, high[1])

pvh1_0 = array.get(first_order_pvhs, 0)
pvh1_1 = array.get(first_order_pvhs, 1)
pvh1_2 = array.get(first_order_pvhs, 2)

if pvh1_1 > pvh1_0 and pvh1_1 > pvh1_2
    array.unshift(second_order_pvhs, pvh1_1)

pvh2_0 = array.get(second_order_pvhs, 0)
pvh2_1 = array.get(second_order_pvhs, 1)
pvh2_2 = array.get(second_order_pvhs, 2)

if pvh2_1 > pvh2_0 and pvh2_1 > pvh2_2
    array.unshift(third_order_pvhs, pvh2_1)
```

You can see my implementation here : [Higher Order Pivots](https://www.tradingview.com/script/x2LlRvBe-Higher-Order-Pivots/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your great support! Your Solution works fine!